# Help with limit evaluation

Tags: limits

Okay so I have to find this limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}-e+\frac{ex}{2}}{11x^2}$$

I could have used the expansion of $(1+x)^\frac{1}{n}$ had $n$ been an integral value , but since it approaches 0 in this case , what are my best options to solve this limit ?

$(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}$ turns to an indeterminate form of $1^{\infty}$.Can I separately solve it and put its limiting value in my question above ?

Comment: I asked a very similar question just few minutes ago. Look at the taylor series of your function.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2556766/limit-as-x-to-0-of-frac1x1-x-ex

Comment: Wow thanks ! I feel stupid now !

Comment: Yeah me too feel stupid.

Comment: Are you by any chance preparing for the JEE ?

Comment: Yeah, but aren't most stupids doing that :)

Comment: Yeah , me too bro ! What books do you solve ?

Comment: I recommend you to come on this chat: [PSS](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54160/problem-solving-strategies)

Comment: **No one here has to feel stupid !**

Comment: This is best handled by Taylor series. You can just try to get the Taylor series via $(1+x)^{1/x}=\exp(1-x/2+x^2/3+\dots)$ which leads to $e(1-x/2+11x^2/24+\dots)$.

Comment: Thank you sir ,  I figured it out . I wish I could ask you all of my doubts. Can  this be made possible anyhow ?